# update table with différents conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, case

I want to make an update in my Student table ( colums : Id, name , age UpdatedDate) according two conditions:

```
@id = 10
UPDATE Student SET Id = @id, UpdatedDate = GETDATE() WHERE Name = "David"
IF age is NULL AND @id = 10 UPDATE Student SET Id = @id, UpdatedDate = GETDATE(), age = 22 WHERE Name = "David"
```

how can I do this update in a more optimal way please ?
the two updates are similar except the difference of a column that we only update if a condition is verified
thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to `UPDATE` by `CASE WHEN` expression, Making your expectation condition then return result to `UPDATE`, otherwise use original value in `ELSE` do nothing.

```
UPDATE Student 
SET Id = @id, 
    UpdatedDate = GETDATE(),
    age = (CASE WHEN age is NULL AND @id = 10 THEN 22 ELSE age END)
WHERE Name = 'David'
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=01c0ac50eb7d100682e6ffee0568f345)